# isotope forcing obtects to 1 column in IE 9

Tags: jquery-isotope

I've programmed and tested my isotope grid in all browsers and it's working great -- in all but IE9!

When the page loads, IE 9 forces the grid into 1 column. I have masonry on and set to calculate the container width and divide by 3 for the column width. IE 9 blinks with the correct output, then, like I said, forces the items to 1 column.

[I've read this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14826537/why-does-isotope-js-plugin-push-elements-into-1-column)

and I've implemented all those things. Still not working.

```
.isotope({
  // other options...
  // disable automatic resizing when window is resized
  resizable: false,
  // set columnWidth option for masonry
  masonry: {
    columnWidth: colWidth,
    gutterWidth: 0
  }
});
```

any help would be awesome. sorry no sample. the dev site is under lock and key.

Comment: In case anyone was wondering, it was all worked out with simple CSS. In the grid, I had the LI set to float:left. by adding display:inline-block, everything works! go figure.